# Create a simple rank array using map function (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, map-function

So essentially I have a JSON that it's in the format as so:

```
JSON= [
{username: foo, score: 12343}, 
{username: bar, score: 9432}, 
{username: foo-bar, score: 402, ...
]
```

I know that the JSON that I am getting back is already rank from highest to lowest, based on the scores.

How can I make an array that automatically inserts the rank position? For instance, I would like to see an output of :

```
[1, username: foo, score: 12343],
[2, username: bar, score: 9432], 
[3, username: foo-bar, score: 402],...
```

Comment: That isn't valid JS - also, those numbers already exist in the JSON response anyway as array indexes + 1.

Comment: Neither of your two JSON strings is actually valid JSON or JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript got you covered already. An array always has indexes, though it starts at zero. If you want the best, just use

```
console.log(JSON[0]);
```

and if you insist on 1 being 1, try this

```
function getByRank(index) {
   return JSON[index - 1]; 
}
```

so you will get the best with

```
console.log(getByRank(1)); // {username: "foo", score: 12343}
```

I think in your code the json is valid json, see the `"` around foo...

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax seems off, but assuming that the JSON is:

```
JSON = [
  {username: 'foo', score: 12343}, 
  {username: 'bar', score: 9432}, 
  {username: 'foo-bar', score: 402}
]
```

Since Arrays are 0 indexed and you have access to the current index in a [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method, you can do something along the following:

```
JSON = JSON.map(function (record, index) {
  record.rank = index + 1;
  return record;
})
```

This should give you the following output:

```
[ 
  { rank: 1, username: 'foo', score: 12343 },
  { rank: 2, username: 'bar', score: 9432},
  { rank: 3, username: 'foo-bar', score: 402}
]
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly from the point of view of your question, you already got the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39130511/create-a-simple-rank-array-using-map-function-javascript/39131007#39131007). I just want to enumerate some ideas, maybe they will be useful to some of you in the future:

1. First of all, JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is an open-standard format that uses human-readable text to serialize objects, arrays, numbers, strings, booleans, and null. Its syntax, as the name states, is derived from JavaScript, but JSON is actually a text, a string.
2. A JSON string is ([almost always](http://timelessrepo.com/json-isnt-a-javascript-subset)) syntactically correct
   JavaScript code.
3. Make sure you don't use the keyword "JSON" as the name of a variable, because JSON is actually an [existing object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.12) in JavaScript, and it is used to encode to JSON format (stringify) and decode from JSON format (parse).
   Just try `JSON.stringify({a: 2, b: 3});` and `JSON.parse('{"a":2,"b":3}');` in a JavaScript console.